# What am I doing wrong in this use of split?

Tags: align, split

I'm doing something wrong in the code below that makes the last equation not be written on a line by itself.  What I'm trying to do is to split the penultimate equation into two lines.  But this happens:

[image]

The last equation continues on the right for some reason.  Can you spot what is the problem?

```
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newcommand{\q}[2]{\langle #1 | #2 \rangle}
\newcommand{\qr}[1]{|#1\rangle} 
\newcommand{\ql}[1]{\langle #1|} 
\DeclareMathOperator{\mdc}{mdc}

\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
  \qr{\psi_2} &= U_f \qr{\psi_1}\\
              &= U_f \frac{1}{\sqrt{2^4}} \left[\qr0 + \qr1 + \qr2+\qr3+\qr4+\qr5+\qr6 + \qr{7}\right] \qr0 \qr0\\
              &= U_f \frac{1}{\sqrt{2^4}} \left[\qr0\qr0 + \qr1\qr0 + \qr2\qr0+\qr3\qr0+\qr4\qr0+\qr5\qr0+\qr6\qr0 + \qr{7}\qr0\right] \qr0\\
\begin{split}
              &= \frac{1}{\sqrt{2^4}} \big[U_f\qr0\qr0 + U_f\qr1\qr0 + U_f\qr2\qr0+U_f\qr3\qr0 \\
              &\qquad\qquad + U_f\qr4\qr0+U_f\qr5\qr0+U_f\qr6\qr0 + U_f\qr{7}\qr0\big] \qr0\\
\end{split}
              &= \frac{1}{\sqrt{2^4}} \left[\qr0\qr2 + \qr1\qr4 + ... + \qr{i}\qr{f(i)} + ... + \qr{7}\qr1\right] \qr0,
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

EDIT: I must've been very tired when I wrote this question because, if you know a little quantum computing, you can see I should have 16 states and not 8 as I wrote.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you're aiming for, but have you tried commenting out the `\begin{split}` and `\end{split}`, and leaving the inner two lines alone?

Comment: Wow.  Why am I using split in the first place?  I thought this wouldn't work at all.

Comment: Needless to say, @Teepeemm, you're answered the question completely.

Comment: But a two line comment takes far less effort than a complete answer.  I'm content with letting those wanting to take the time to also take the points.

Comment: @Mico added the very interesting suggestion of `U_{\!f}` in lieu of `U_f`.  I had not even detected the cosmetic problem of the subscript being a little far from its main symbol, so I'll choose his answer.  Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In addition to getting rid of the unneeded `split` environment, you may want to (a) typeset the `U_f` terms more compactly, i.e., as `U_{\!f}`, (b) replace various `\left[` and `\right]` directives with `\bigl[` and `\bigr]`, and (c) replace `...` with `\dots`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools} % for '\DeclarePairedDelimiter' macro
\DeclarePairedDelimiter\qr\lvert\rangle
\newcommand{\Uf}{U_{\!f}}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
\qr{\psi_2} 
&= \Uf \qr{\psi_1}\\
&= \Uf \frac{1}{\sqrt{2^4}} 
   \bigl[\qr0 + \qr1 + \qr2+\qr3 +\qr4 
   +\qr5 +\qr6 + \qr7\bigr] \qr0 \qr0\\
&= \Uf \frac{1}{\sqrt{2^4}} 
   \bigl[\qr0\qr0 + \qr1\qr0 + \qr2\qr0+\qr3\qr0
   +\qr4\qr0+\qr5\qr0+\qr6\qr0 + \qr7\qr0\bigr] \qr0\\
&= \frac{1}{\sqrt{2^4}} 
   \bigl[\Uf\qr0\qr0 + \Uf\qr1\qr0 + \Uf\qr2\qr0+\Uf\qr3\qr0 \\
&\qquad\qquad 
   + \Uf\qr4\qr0+\Uf\qr5\qr0+\Uf\qr6\qr0 
   + \Uf\qr7\qr0\bigr] \qr0\\
&= \frac{1}{\sqrt{2^4}} 
   \bigl[\qr0\qr2 + \qr1\qr4 + \dots 
   + \qr{i}\qr{f(i)} + \dots + \qr7\qr1\bigr] \qr0,
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Very interesting suggestions.  (Thank you!)

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using the `multlined` environment from `mathtools`, and the `\DeclarePairedDelimiter` command from the same package, which will produce scaling `\, \qr` and `\ql`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\DeclarePairedDelimiterX\norm[1]\lVert\rVert{\ifblank{#1}{\: · \:}{#1}}
\DeclarePairedDelimiterXPP{\twonorm }[1]{}{\lVert}{\rVert}{_{2}}{\ifblank{#1}{\: · \:}{#1}}
\DeclarePairedDelimiterX\q[2]{\langle}{\rangle}%
{#1\,\delimsize\vert\,\mathopen{}#2}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\qr}\vert\rangle
\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\ql}\langle \rvert
\DeclareMathOperator{\mdc}{mdc}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
  \qr{\psi_2} &= U_f \qr{\psi_1}\\
              &= U_f \frac{1}{\sqrt{2^4}} \bigl[\qr0 + \qr1 + \qr2+\qr3+\qr4+\qr5+\qr6 + \qr{7}\bigr] \qr0 \qr0\\
              &= U_f \frac{1}{\sqrt{2^4}}\bigl[\qr0\qr0 + \qr1\qr0 + \qr2\qr0+\qr3\qr0+\qr4\qr0+\qr5\qr0+\qr6\qr0 + \qr{7}\qr0\bigr] \qr0\\
              &= \begin{multlined}[t] \frac{1}{\sqrt{2^4}} \bigl[U_f\qr0\qr0 + U_f\qr1\qr0 + U_f\qr2\qr0+U_f\qr3\qr0 \\[-1.5ex]
             \qquad+ U_f\qr4\qr0+U_f\qr5\qr0+U_f\qr6\qr0 + U_f\qr{7}\qr0\bigr] \qr0
\end{multlined}\\
              &= \frac{1}{\sqrt{2^4}}\bigl[\qr0\qr2 + \qr1\qr4 + ... + \qr{i}\qr{f(i)} + ... + \qr{7}\qr1\bigr] \qr0,
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The `\left` and `\right` directives don't succeed in making "big" square brackets -- better to use `\bigl[` and `\bigr]`, right? :-)

Comment: That's right. Actually, I didn't think about this problem,  but I see I should have, to make the formula a little less unpleasant to read. I'll fix that. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `aligned` instead of `split`, but also `split` could do provided you issue `\\` at the right spot.

Instead of making your own bras and kets, it's better if you use a specialized package such as `braket`. I also removed all useless `\left` and `\right`, which don't do anything beyond adding unnecessary space, using instead `\bigl` and `\bigr` (not `\big`).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{braket}

\newcommand{\q}[2]{\braket{#1|#2}}
\newcommand{\qr}[1]{\ket{#1}}
\newcommand{\ql}[1]{\bra{#1}}

\DeclareMathOperator{\mdc}{mdc}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
\qr{\psi_2}
&= U_f \qr{\psi_1}\\
&= U_f \frac{1}{\sqrt{2^4}}
   \bigl[\qr0 + \qr1 + \qr2 + \qr3 + \qr4 + \qr5 + \qr6 + \qr{7}\bigr] \qr0 \qr0 \\
&= U_f \frac{1}{\sqrt{2^4}}
   \bigl[
     \qr0\qr0 + \qr1\qr0 + \qr2\qr0 + \qr3\qr0 + \qr4\qr0 +
     \qr5\qr0 + \qr6\qr0 + \qr{7}\qr0
   \bigr] \qr0 \\
&= \begin{aligned}[t]
   \frac{1}{\sqrt{2^4}}
   \bigl[
    &U_f\qr0\qr0 + U_f\qr1\qr0 + U_f\qr2\qr0+U_f\qr3\qr0 \\
    &\quad+ U_f\qr4\qr0+U_f\qr5\qr0+U_f\qr6\qr0 + U_f\qr{7}\qr0
   \bigr] \qr0
\end{aligned}\\
&= \frac{1}{\sqrt{2^4}}
   \bigl[
     \qr0\qr2 + \qr1\qr4 + \dots + \qr{i}\qr{f(i)} + \dots + \qr{7}\qr1
   \bigr] \qr0,
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

You get essentially the same with `split`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{braket}
\newcommand{\q}[2]{\braket{#1|#2}}
\newcommand{\qr}[1]{\ket{#1}}
\newcommand{\ql}[1]{\bra{#1}}

\DeclareMathOperator{\mdc}{mdc}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
\qr{\psi_2}
&= U_f \qr{\psi_1}\\
&= U_f \frac{1}{\sqrt{2^4}}
   \bigl[\qr0 + \qr1 + \qr2 + \qr3 + \qr4 + \qr5 + \qr6 + \qr{7}\bigr] \qr0 \qr0 \\
&= U_f \frac{1}{\sqrt{2^4}}
   \bigl[
     \qr0\qr0 + \qr1\qr0 + \qr2\qr0 + \qr3\qr0 + \qr4\qr0 +
     \qr5\qr0 + \qr6\qr0 + \qr{7}\qr0
   \bigr] \qr0 \\
\begin{split}
&=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2^4}}
   \bigl[
    U_f\qr0\qr0 + U_f\qr1\qr0 + U_f\qr2\qr0+U_f\qr3\qr0 \\
    &\qquad\qquad+ U_f\qr4\qr0+U_f\qr5\qr0+U_f\qr6\qr0 + U_f\qr{7}\qr0
   \bigr] \qr0
\end{split}\\
&= \frac{1}{\sqrt{2^4}}
   \bigl[
     \qr0\qr2 + \qr1\qr4 + \dots + \qr{i}\qr{f(i)} + \dots + \qr{7}\qr1
   \bigr] \qr0,
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the reason you are getting this result is that the second linebreak inside the `split` environment should be outside, like this:

```
\begin{align*}
  \qr{\psi_2} &= U_f \qr{\psi_1}\\
              &= U_f \frac{1}{\sqrt{2^4}} \left[\qr0 + \qr1 + \qr2+\qr3+\qr4+\qr5+\qr6 + \qr{7}\right] \qr0 \qr0\\
              &= U_f \frac{1}{\sqrt{2^4}} \left[\qr0\qr0 + \qr1\qr0 + \qr2\qr0+\qr3\qr0+\qr4\qr0+\qr5\qr0+\qr6\qr0 + \qr{7}\qr0\right] \qr0\\
\begin{split}
              &= \frac{1}{\sqrt{2^4}} \big[U_f\qr0\qr0 + U_f\qr1\qr0 + U_f\qr2\qr0+U_f\qr3\qr0 \\
              &\qquad\qquad + U_f\qr4\qr0+U_f\qr5\qr0+U_f\qr6\qr0 + U_f\qr{7}\qr0\big] \qr0
\end{split}\\
              &= \frac{1}{\sqrt{2^4}} \left[\qr0\qr2 + \qr1\qr4 + ... + \qr{i}\qr{f(i)} + ... + \qr{7}\qr1\right] \qr0,
\end{align*}
```

Besides the recomendations given in Bernard's answer, I'd also suggest using the `split` environment inside `equation*` instead of `align*`, since it seems you're trying to typeset just one (albeit multi-line) equation:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newcommand{\q}[2]{\langle #1 | #2 \rangle}
\newcommand{\qr}[1]{|#1\rangle} 
\newcommand{\ql}[1]{\langle #1|} 
\DeclareMathOperator{\mdc}{mdc}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
 \begin{split}
  \qr{\psi_2} &= U_f \qr{\psi_1}\\
              &= U_f \frac{1}{\sqrt{2^4}} \left[\qr0 + \qr1 + \qr2+\qr3+\qr4+\qr5+\qr6 + \qr{7}\right] \qr0 \qr0\\
              &= U_f \frac{1}{\sqrt{2^4}} \left[\qr0\qr0 + \qr1\qr0 + \qr2\qr0+\qr3\qr0+\qr4\qr0+\qr5\qr0+\qr6\qr0 + \qr{7}\qr0\right] \qr0\\
              &=\!\begin{multlined}[t] \frac{1}{\sqrt{2^4}} \big[U_f\qr0\qr0 + U_f\qr1\qr0 + U_f\qr2\qr0+U_f\qr3\qr0 \\[-1.5ex]
             \qquad+ U_f\qr4\qr0+U_f\qr5\qr0+U_f\qr6\qr0 + U_f\qr{7}\qr0\big] \qr0
\end{multlined}\\
              &= \frac{1}{\sqrt{2^4}} \left[\qr0\qr2 + \qr1\qr4 + ... + \qr{i}\qr{f(i)} + ... + \qr{7}\qr1\right] \qr0,
 \end{split}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: But how to align the equal signs within  `equation`? `align` is appropriate here.

Comment: I forgot to add that I'd recomend using the `split` environment to align the equal signs and the multlined environment to break one the lines into two.